# How can I combine two lists?

Tags: excel

I was wondering how I can insert a data from one table to another.

For example, lets say we have a table with the titles

```
ID  NAME
1   Joe
2   Bob
2   Adam
```

and another table with the titles

```
ID  COLOR
1   Red
2   Green
```

Depending on the ID value, I want to add the COLOR data to the first table so it will look like

```
ID  NAME   COLOR
1   Joe    Red
2   Bob    Gren
2   Adam   Green
```

I apologize for the format, wasn't sure how to make a table. The tables can be on a same sheet or can be different sheets. I have multiple tables that I want to combine and if I can get any help I would appreciate it.

Comment: Thanks i'll check that out!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need a simple `VLOOKUP` function. This [link](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/vlookup.php) will get you started.

Comment: Thanks i'll check it out!